# In-App purchase with Windows phone8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

I have developed an Win-Phone8 application, Initially for 15 days I am giving my application for trail period and after 15 days the user have to subscribe the application (They can purchase) to use it uninterruptedly rest of the time , I was planning to use third party payment gateways like (Stripe,Paypal) but I think the Platform like Windows only allowing third party payment gateways for selling physical goods like (Books , Electronics items etc. ) But in our case we just going to sell an upgraded App which is a digital content.My Question is can we sell the App Upgrade features through Stripe payment gateway or any third party payment gateway??? IF not I found the platform Windows providing Service API's for In-App Purchase inside the App. So My Question is, Do i need only In-App purchase service for selling App in Windowsstore???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In-app purchase given by Microsoft is enough for selling apps in windows store. You don't need to worry about third party payment gateway etc.

refer to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj206949(v=vs.105).aspx

examples given on this page are useful.

Comment: My Question is can i user third party payment gateways? Instead of windows library

Comment: sure as long as third party gateways provide you api on windows phone. you can integrate seamless or non-seamless integration.

Comment: unfortunately most of TPL i have worked with supports only android, iOS. If you come across any such library which supports on windows phone do share here

Comment: Yes you are right i have worked with "Stripe" and "Paypal" both supports IOS and Android but not windows but I think you can use javascipts inside webview on windows ryt?

Comment: yes you can. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-intercept-854d33da  Please mark above answer as accepted

Comment: So In that way we can use payment gateways in Windows like Stripe and PayPal?

Comment: yes, but will recommend to contact paypal etc to make sure development is done using their standards

Comment: Thanks amod for the clarification